# Server returns 400 error when I send data using PostAsync

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am using the following method to post to a web service. When I use it, I constantly get a 400 error. If I use the same data that I pass in though using Posty, the service returns the expected data

```
public static async Task<T> SendData<T>(string apiToUse, params string[] data)
    {
        var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}", Constants.BaseTestUrl, apiToUse);

        dynamic t;

        var kvp = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 2)
        {
            kvp.Add(data[i], data[i + 1]);
        }

        var dta = new FormUrlEncodedContent(kvp);
        dta.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var result = client.PostAsync(url, dta).Result;
            //result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
            var rv = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rv);
        }

        return t;
    }
```

In my test example, I pass into the param string[] data the two keys and two values.

The only thing that I can see that is different is that on posty I have the Content-Type defined before I click send (which I have also done here).

This is driving me somewhat insane, so any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the target url is correct? I thought HttpClient needed a base address in its constructor and then worked off relative addresses on its methods.

Comment: A HTTP response code in 400 means something is wrong with your request. Without knowing the service you're trying to post to, and what it expects, there's not really a lot that we can suggest. Check the documentation for the API you are trying to consume, and ensure you are correctly formatting your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to provide a complete answer without exactly knowing how the request should look like. Can you try / adjust the code as follows:

```
 var kvp = string.Empty;

 for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 2)
 {
     kvp += string.Format("{0}={1}; ", data[i], data[i+1]);
 }

 // remove last ';' character
 kvp = kvp.TrimEnd(new char[] { ' ', ';' });

 var dta = new MultipartFormDataContent();
 dta.Add(new StringContent(kvp));
```

The change consists in using `MultipartFormDataContent` to comply with the request format. Obviously, this code is just for testing. Additional validation and content creation (`kvp`) should be done before placing it into production.